# One class, two class loaders

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, classloader

I'm trying to start some bundles from eclipse in Intellij.
The problem is after I do:

```
FrameworkFactory fFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
Framework framework = fFactory.newFramework(config);...
context = framework.getBundleContext();
bundle = context.installBundle(myBundle);
bundle.start();
```

and I want to use a class from my Bundle, I see that my class is loaded again by another class loader. So, what should I do to be able to use the same classes that were loaded when i started the bundle?
The two class loaders are:

```
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader
java.net.URLClassLoader
```

Comment: What do you mean "I want to use a class from my Bundle"? You mean you want to get a class from inside the bundle and use it outside the bundle, i.e. from your outer application?

Comment: Yes, this is what i meant.

Comment: As indicated below: that is not possible for user classes. Can you  indicate what is the exact purpose of this action? Maybe there is another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally due to an incorrect specification of the Import-Package and Export-Package headers. Make sure that the class you refer to is imported from the same bundle. In that case the class loader for the class will be the same.

Unless of course you are really asking why a class *within* the framework (so from the bundle you started) is not loaded by the same class loader *outside* the framework (in this case the code starting the framework). In that case the answer would be: never (apart from maybe the classes loaded by the JVM bootstrap itself) and I would suggest you to get a better understanding of the framework concept in OSGi.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. I am trying to make a plugin for Intellij (and i need to use the bundles from eclipse). Is there a way in which i can use classes from within the framework when, let's say, a menu button is clicked?

Comment: I am not familiar with IntelliJ plugins, but plugins from eclipse are, as other OSGi bundles, normal jars. You can just add them to your classpath and instantiate the class. But if you expect eclipse user interface actions to be integrated with ItelliJ: that, I guess, will not happen.

Comment: I not familiar with them neither, but IntelliJ platform is not based on OSGI and i have to start the bundles manually...

Comment: As stated: you don't have to approach a bundle as a bundle (and don't have to start it), you can use it as a normal set of classes as in a normal jar. If your purpose is to use some functionality from a class in a bundle, you can just instantiate the class and use it as you normally would with a library jar.